# Any way to update now from iOS 7.0.4 to 7.1.2?

Tags: iphone, ios, restore

I am trying to restore my iPhone 5s to iOS 7.1.2 but I only get error 3194. My hosts file is cleaned and I think it’s just Apple that doesn’t let me update to something other than iOS 8. Is there any other way to restore my phone to iOS 7? While trying to restore content and settings it got stuck in an endless spinner.

Comment: Check this OSXDaily article: http://osxdaily.com/2014/09/21/downgrade-ios-8-back-to-ios-7-1-2/

You can download ipsw and upload it via iTunes.

Comment: That's how i get the 3194. This article is from 21/09/14 when iOS 8 was suffering with issues. Now with iOS 8.0.2 is Apple still signing iOS 7 restores? And if not, is a workaround to bypass apple check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple is no longer signing iOS 7, while you can manually update to v7.1.2, it won't activate.

http://appleinsider.com/articles/14/09/26/apple-stops-ios-712-code-signing-restricts-downgrading-from-ios-8

Comment: Thanks a lot Patrick! I just did a [semi-restore](http://www.semi-restore.com) so i am ok for now...